# Ambiguity of the DGCA tag

Tags: discussion, tags, tag-synonyms, retagging

I just stumbled across a [dgca-regulations](https://aviation.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/dgca-regulations) tag. According to the description it is for question related to regulations by the Directorate General of Civil Aviation in India.

While the tag-wiki clearly refers to India, the term DGCA / DGAC is used in many countries. For example:

- [Bolivia](http://www.dgac.gob.bo) (DGAC)
- [Chile](http://www.dgac.gob.cl) (DGAC)
- Costa Rica (DGAC)
- Ecuador (DGAC)
- [France](http://www.immat.aviation-civile.gouv.fr/) (DGAC)
- Guatemala (DGAC)
- [India](http://dgca.nic.in/) (DGCA)
- Indonesia (DGCA)
- [Kuwait](http://www.dgca.gov.kw/)(DGCA)
- [Peru](https://www.mtc.gob.pe/portal/transportes/aereo/aeronauticacivil/contenido.htm) (DGAC)
- Turkey (DGCA)

I propose the rename the tag to[dgca-india](https://aviation.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/dgca-india) and label DGCA's /DGAC's from other countries in the same way.

Since the name of the Civil Aviation Authorities (the generic term used in ICAO) varies from country to country we should consider to make synonyms in the form of [caa-india](https://aviation.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/caa-india) so that the right tag is easily found.

---

**Update:**

I've converted [dgca-regulations](https://aviation.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/dgca-regulations) to [dgca-india-regulations](https://aviation.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/dgca-india-regulations). For creating synonyms I didn't have enough votes on these tags.

Comment: I like this, but we should have  dgca-india and dgca-india-regulations  we do for the faa.

Comment: Seems sensible - retagging is a manual thing so we'll need to go cull [tag:dgca] / [tag:dgca-regulations] over time & move questions into appropriate national tags. (I hope nobody else has a "FAA" - that's probably too much to retag at this point :)